# How to gray a group of widgets when they are disabled?

Tags: qt

There is a QGroupBox full of widgets, and all of them need to be disabled and grayed out.

setDisabled(true) does disable them functionally, but they don't turn gray.

What is the easiest and most proper way to turn them gray?
This should be a standard operation: text turns gray so that users can easily see that they are disabled.

Comment: Actually, there are various reasons possible why you widgets aren't gray what not necessarily means that `setDisabled()` doesn't work. (I elaborated this a little bit in my answer.) Please, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, it is not possible to confirm your observation or find out what's happening at all.

Answer (score 1):

[`QWidget::setDisabled()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setDisabled) is yet (another) slot for the [`QWidget` `enabled` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop).

From Qt doc.:

> This property holds whether the widget is enabled
>
> In general an enabled widget handles keyboard and mouse events; a disabled widget does not. An exception is made with [QAbstractButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html).
>
> Some widgets display themselves differently when they are disabled. For example a button **might** draw its label grayed out.

(Emphasizing by me.)

How widgets are displayed depends on their respective rendering as well as the (default) [`QStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#details) which is used in the application.

Concerning custom widgets (classes derived from any "built-in" Qt widget) where `paintEvent()` is overloaded, the custom widget is itself responsible to render accordingly to different states.